# Extracting data from net ldap response containing image

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openldap, netldap

In my application I sync users image uploaded as photo field in the LDAP, I am using NET::LDAP for the same.

the object returned for the image field is of type Net::BER::BerIdentifiedArray, I can convert it to Net::BER.

My question is how do I extract the type of image(jpeg/gif/bmp etc) while creating a image file from the binary response given by the LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something to decode the binary data into an image.  [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) is a Ruby wrapper for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) that should do the trick.  Specifically, [`Image.from_blob`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob) will read image data from a string in memory.

From there, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840112/how-to-get-image-type-with-rmagick) shows `image.format` will tell you the format.